# Add build link to work item using REST API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have a build which is triggered by another build. The triggering build has work items linked to it.
For better visibility I want to link all the work items that are linked to triggering build also to the triggered build. I already have everything in place to pull the list of work items but I can't find the way to link the work items to a build using REST API
Trying to use the Work Items - Update add a link option
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link

The Work Items Relation Types - List returns:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20relation%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

```
System.LinkTypes.Remote.Dependency-Forward
System.LinkTypes.Remote.Dependency-Reverse
System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Forward
System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Reverse
Microsoft.VSTS.TestCase.SharedParameterReferencedBy-Forward
Microsoft.VSTS.TestCase.SharedParameterReferencedBy-Reverse
Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Affects-Forward
Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Affects-Reverse
Microsoft.VSTS.TestCase.SharedStepReferencedBy-Forward
Microsoft.VSTS.TestCase.SharedStepReferencedBy-Reverse
Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward
Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Reverse
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Forward
System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Reverse
System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward
System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse
System.LinkTypes.Related
System.LinkTypes.Remote.Related
AttachedFile
Hyperlink
ArtifactLink
```

Except the last 3, all seems to be WI to WI relation. How do I add a link to a build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unachievable currently. There are three external link types(Pipelines/build, Found in build, Integrated in build) that are used to link a work item to a build as described in the [Link types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#external-link-types) document.

However, i found above **Build** relation types is not listed in above returned Relation Types. I tried and only made it adding a build as a **Hyperlink**.

For a workaround,You can try adding the build to the workitem as **[Hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-hyperlink)** currently.

You can report this problem to Microsoft Development team [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). Hope they can look into this problem.

[image]

Comment: I opened a feature request. Hopefully it will be added soon.

Answer (score 5):

The correct Relation Type is ArtifactLink.

I used the following powershell code in my pipeline to create these links:

```
$personalToken = "<insert personal token here>"
 
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

$buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
$azureDevOpsOrg = "<insert your organization name here>"
$projectName = "<insert your project name here>"

$buildWorkItemsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/${azureDevOpsOrg}/${projectName}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/workitems?api-version=5.0"

$body = "[
  {
    ""op"": ""add"",
    ""path"": ""/relations/-"",
    ""value"": {
      ""rel"": ""ArtifactLink"",
      ""url"": ""vstfs:///Build/Build/${buildId}"",
      ""attributes"": {
        ""name"": ""Integrated in build""
      }
    }
  }
]"

$workItems = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildWorkItemsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

$workItems.value | ForEach-Object {
  $workItemId = $_.id
  Write-Host $workItemId
  $updateWorkItemurl = "https://dev.azure.com/${azureDevOpsOrg}/${projectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=6.0"
  Write-Host $updateWorkItemurl
  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateWorkItemurl -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers $header -Body $body
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution now, since at least API 6.0