# How can we add existing links in Azure DevOps programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I want to link the existing work items which are already created in a project under Azure DevOps by writing a code or program in C#, so is there any kind of API or SDK which can be used to link the work items programmatically?

The Workitems can be of any type i.e.

- Bug
- User Story
- Issue
- Task etc.

The linking between the Workitems can also be of any type i.e. Relational, Parent-Child, etc.

Recently I referred to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c3deb80-cbb4-4b00-afdb-dca6cfb63087/create-onetomany-work-item-links-programmatically-in-tfs-2013?forum=tfsworkitemtracking) for my problem.

The link contains issue very much related and similar to mine, however it is not working as expected when I tried it.

Comment: Welcome.  Sadly _[questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_.  Good luck!

Comment: _"when I tried it it is not working as expected."_ I'd suggest to rephrase the question to focus on this point. Please provide the relevant  code that you tried and that is not working ([mcve]), with some information about what you mean by "not working" (error? no effect? unexpected output?)

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
//int relatedId = ...
//int id = ...
//CancellationToken token = ...
//string organization = ...
//string projectName = ...
//WorkItemTrackingHttpClient azureClient = ...
```

Create a JsonPatchDocument as below:

```
JsonPatchDocument patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument();
patchDoc.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation
    {
        From = null,
        Operation = Operation.Add,
        Path = "/relations/-",
        Value = new {
                        rel = "System.LinkTypes.Related",
                        url = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectName}/_workitems/edit/{relatedId}",
                        attributes = new
                        {
                            comment = $"Created programmatically on {DateTime.Now}."
                        }
                    }
    }
);
```

and call this async method of Azure DevOps SDK:

```
await azureClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDoc, id, false, true, true, WorkItemExpand.All, cancellationToken: token);
```

In the case above we created a related link using `System.LinkTypes.Related` referenceName.
For a full link types reference guide in Azure DevOps refer to this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184540/add-build-link-to-work-item-using-rest-api)'s question or this [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops)'s doc.